# How do I move input value to the right side

Tags: html, css, input

How do I move input value to the right side of the input box with css?

```html
<input id="calc" value="0">
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
#calc {
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input id="calc" value="0">
```